# How to extract only files without creating directory paths from tar.gz file?

Tags: tar

I have a `tar.gz` file from which I have to extract only the files in current directory without creating the whole structure.

**For example**:

`tar.gz` contains below files,

```
/u01/app/oracle/file1
..
..
/u01/app/oracle/file10
/u01/testdata/file1
..
..
/u01/testdata/file5
```

the `tar.gz` is present in `/u02`. So when extracting I want `file1` through `file10` coming under `/u02` instead, the whole directory structure is getting created under `/u02`

Answer (score 3):

Since you seem to have a fixed number of path components, pass [--strip-components=3](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC116) to `tar` to remove `/u01/app/oracle` while extracting to `/u02`

For a variable number of components, use the `--transform` flag instead. Something along the lines of `--transform='s,^\([^/][^/]*/\)\+,,'`

Comment: Ok, this will work when tar contains files from one location. But this tar has files from 2 different locations with varying path lengths. I did not mention that in example.

Comment: @GirishSunkara, see edit

Answer (score 2):

With the standard `pax` command:

```
gunzip < file.tar.gz | pax -r's|.*/||p'
```

Comment: That works!!! exactly what I am looking for... Can you please explain the logic how it is doing it?